# Python - Ranking values according to size in an another array

Tags: python

Say I have a list in python:

```
numArray = [3.7, 1, 7.2, 5]
```

And I want to create another list that has the rank of every corresponding element in numArray in it. It would like:

```
rank = [3,4,1,2]
```

3.7 is the third largest number in the list, so it has a rank of 3. This is done for every element in the array. Assume that the array only contains numerical values as opposed to strings or any other data type.

My thought process right now is:

1) copy the elements into another array

2) sort them into using list.sort() -- now I have the values from least to greatest

My problem now is that I can't affiliate element rank based on the sorted list

Thanks!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: if a list is sorted it's "rank" would be determined by the index of that value, so you could just use the `.index` method assuming no duplicates.  What is the actual issue you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the cleanest/"pythonic" solution, but in the meantime, it should do the job:

```
numArray = [3.7, 1, 7.2, 5]
rank = []
for i in numArray:
    rank.append(sorted(numArray)[::-1].index(i)+1)

print rank # [3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Update:
Here's the one-liner:

```
rank = [numArray.index(i)+1 for i in sorted(numArray)[::-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a mapping of numbers to rank values, that way you can iterate over the original list and lookup the rank value for each number.

```
num_list = [3.7, 1, 7.2, 5]
num_ranks = dict(zip(sorted(num_list, reverse=True), range(1, len(num_list)+1)))
rank = [num_ranks[v] for v in num_list]
```